# Listing installed NuGet packages and their version from C#

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm playing with creating a small tool that can list installed NuGet packages and their versions in a local project. I know, there are multiple tools out there that do something similar but this is only as a small hobby project to learn something new ;)

There are some good samples around how to interact with the NuGet API here: https://github.com/NuGet/Samples. But I cannot seem to find any examples of how to resolve installed packages. I could simply parse the `csproj` file with an XML parser or something like that and look for packages. I'm just thinking that one of the official `NuGet.*` packages have something to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all local packages in the NuGet v3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898032/how-can-i-list-all-local-packages-in-the-nuget-v3-api) Parsing the XML file is a simpler solution aswell.

Comment: `I could simply parse the csproj file with an XML parser or something like that and look for packages.` -- Yes, I think that would be a reasonable approach.

Comment: @SeanPowell I'm not sure this answer my question. I tried the code from that question. I believe the intent there is to list NuGet packages on a locally hosted feed. That's not what I'm trying to do here. I want to see which NuGet packages that are installed in a project.